# Macro variable substitution in printf

Tags: c, macros, printf, c-preprocessor

I wrote a simple program with a single `printf` statement,like hello world.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100
int main()
{
    printf("Max is %d\n",MAX);
}
```

I studied that macros are just substituted in place of occurrence ,by preprocessor. Generally `printf` need a variable name with corresponding format specifier to print the value of variable. 
Here ,with my understanding, 100 should be replaced in `printf` call and should raise an error.

But the output is :

```
Max is 100
```

How and why?

Comment: Why do you think `printf("Max is %d\n",100);`, will give error?

Comment: Why do you think `printf` requires a variable "name"? C does not even know the "names" of variables at run-time. Ever header of _constants_?

Comment: C is pass-by-value, so you never need a variable to pass as argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"Generally `printf()` need a variable name with corresponding format specifier to print the value of variable."*

There you went wrong. All the format specifiers supplied with `printf()` expects an ***argument*** of the particular type, not a ***variable*** of that type. `100`, an [integer literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_literal), is a valid argument for `%d`, in this case.

So, `printf("Max is %d\n",100);` is both a valid and legal statement in `C`. The output you got is expected output, there should be no error or warning with this.

Just to add a reference to the actual words, quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1, `fprintf()` (emphasis mine)

> `d,i`
>
> **The int argument** is converted to [...]

Answer (score 1):

The `printf` format `"%d"` tells `printf` to extract an `int` argument from the argument list. If that `int` comes from a variable or a literal doesn't matter.